# Proguard: -keepparameternames for certain packages only

Tags: proguard, obfuscation

The option -keep allows to exclude from obfuscation, but it still obfuscate the methods parameter names, which can be bad for framework like Spring web.

```
  -keep class com.example.web.** { *; }
```

Is there a way to preserve the arguments names for certain packages only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible:
https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/discussion/182455/thread/59cb6762/

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 0):

From what I've tried the `-keepparameternames` seems to affect only the `-keep-ed` methods.

So the answer to your question: it's possible to limit the list of packages that fall under its action marking with `-keep` (or its derivatives) only certain packages.